# Why would memory corruption exist.. only if we don't print the variable being corrupted?

Tags: c, memory-corruption

I'm having an odd error in C. We have the following code, I first tried it without the middle two `fprintf(f, "Passed PKLEN pklen: %u ,params->pklen: %u \n", pklen, params->pklen);` functions and was getting what appeared to be memory corruption, where `pklen` stopped equalling `params->pklen`.  When I added those two middle `println`'s in order to determine where the actual corruption was occurring... the two equalled eachother by the last one.

```
void ntru_get_seed(uint8_t *msg, uint16_t msg_len, NtruIntPoly *h, uint8_t *b, const NtruEncParams *params, uint8_t *seed) {
  FILE *f = fopen("log.txt", "a");
  uint16_t oid_len = sizeof params->oid;
  uint16_t pklen = params->pklen;
  fprintf(f, "Passed PKLEN pklen: %u ,params->pklen: %u \n", pklen, params->pklen);
  fflush(f);
​
  uint8_t bh[ntru_enc_len(params)];
  fprintf(f, "Passed PKLEN pklen: %u ,params->pklen: %u \n", pklen, params->pklen);

  ntru_to_arr(h, params->q, (uint8_t*)&bh);
  fprintf(f, "Passed PKLEN pklen: %u ,params->pklen: %u \n", pklen, params->pklen);

​
  uint8_t htrunc[pklen/8];
  fprintf(f, "Passed PKLEN pklen: %u ,params->pklen: %u \n", pklen, params->pklen);
  fprintf(f, "bh: %u \n", &bh);
  fflush(f);
...
```

Comment: The general _theory_ is, it's undefined behavior and Schrödinger's cat is a close friend of yours.

Comment: It's a quantum encryption proof library... we were thinking maybe there was some funny quantum stuff going on.  So yeah... you may be on to something with that Schrödinger's cat thing.

Comment: If you have odd error in C why do you past C++ question?

Comment: @mczarnek I doubt the UB was introduced by this particular library, but rather by wrong code provided from your side.

Comment: C code is C++ code...  other way around would be wrong.

We made our own C# wrapper to call the C functions, it's possible it's something there, just seemed odd that it was the println that was changing the corruption and that it would be a C error.

Comment: @mczarnek "C code is C++ code..."  - wrong. For example code you posted is not valid C++ code.

Comment: @mczarnek: Not all legal C code is also legal C++ code, and some of what is legal has different semantics.  Also, you should use the macro `PRIu16` instead of `%u` to print out `uint16_t` values: `printf( "Passed PKLEN pklen: %" PRIu16 ", params->pklen: %" PRIu16 "\n", pklen, params->pklen );`

Comment: Will post it as C in the future then.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh and we found the error, we were creating a public encryption key that was the wrong size in other code due to a typo.  Anyway, it's working now.  Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 7):

Sure. Adding the calls to `fprintf()` moved other parts of your code in memory and changed what was being overwritten.

Put back the old broken code and step through it with a debugger and you can watch what's being overwritten.

Also turn on all the warnings and errors possible and fix your code so you don't get any.